# set multiple select list options to selected from query

Tags: php

I have a field named 'majors' which contains a string of integers seperated by commas.  This field is populated from a multiple select list on insert query using the following variable:

```
$majors_string = implode(",", $majors);
```

Now on the edit page, I want to have those values set the options in the same list.  Part of the problem is that the list is generated dynamically using:

```
<select name="majors[]" size="9" multiple="multiple" id="majors">
          <?php 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from major ORDER BY title ASC");
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($query);$i++) {
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['major_pk']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></option>
          <?php 
}
?>
        </select>
```

On the initial query on the edit page, I have:

```
$query_topic = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE topic_pk = '$topic_pk'";
$result_topic = mysql_query($query_topic, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_topic = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_topic);

$retrieved_majors = explode(",", $row_topic['majors']);
```

But I'm unsure as to set the options in the multiple list to the values in array $retrieved_majors.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps I shouln't be storing the list values as comma delimited string in one field.  What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking how to set the default for which options are selected, right?

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['major_pk']; ?>" <?php if(array_search($row['major_pk'], $retrieved_majors) !== false) {echo 'selected';} ?> ><?php echo $row['title']; ?></option>
```

Comment: Is `$retrieved_majors` set before the loop?

Comment: I don't have a loop yet...  Can you explain how I should handle this?

Comment: You do have a loop, it starts with `for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($query); $i++)`.

Comment: BTW, the usual idiom is `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))`.

Comment: Yes, it should, I've fixed it.