# codeigniter Can't insert field in database

Tags: codeigniter, insert, userid

I build my website but there are some problems , first of this , I can't insert in database .

I tried to do it , but it doesn't work .

any help please

```js
in controllers / cases.php


function add(){
  $data['fields_clients'] = $this->custom_field_model->get_custom_fields(1);
  $data['fields']    = $this->custom_field_model->get_custom_fields(2);
  $data['clients']   = $this->cases_model->get_all_clients();
  $data['stages']    = $this->case_stage_model->get_all();
  $data['acts']     = $this->cases_model->get_all_acts();
  $data['courts']    = $this->cases_model->get_all_courts();
  $data['locations']    = $this->cases_model->get_all_locations();
  $data['case_categories'] = $this->cases_model->get_all_case_categories();
  $data['court_categories']= $this->cases_model->get_all_court_categories();
                $data['city'] = $this->cases_model->get_name_city();
                //$data['employee'] = $this->cases_model->get_name_employee();
  if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        { 
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->form_validation->set_message('required', lang('custom_required'));
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'lang:title', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_id', 'Client', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('case_no', 'Case No', '');        //trim|required|is_unique[cases.case_no]
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('location_id', 'Location', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('case_stage_id', 'Case Stage', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('court_id', 'Court', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('court_category_id', 'Court Category', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('case_category_id', 'Case Category', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('act_id', 'Act', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date', 'Filing Date', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('city_case', 'city case', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('fees', 'Fees', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('o_lawyer', 'Opposite Lawyer', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('hearing_date', 'Description', '');
    
   if ($this->form_validation->run()==true)
            {
    $save['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
    $save['case_no'] = $this->input->post('case_no');
    $save['client_id'] = $this->input->post('client_id');
    $save['location_id'] = $this->input->post('location_id');
    $save['court_id'] = $this->input->post('court_id');
    $save['court_category_id'] = $this->input->post('court_category_id');
    $save['case_stage_id'] = $this->input->post('case_stage_id');
    $save['case_category_id'] = json_encode($this->input->post('case_category_id'));
    $save['act_id'] = json_encode($this->input->post('act_id'));
    $save['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
    $save['start_date'] = $this->input->post('start_date');
    $save['hearing_date'] = $this->input->post('hearing_date');
    $save['o_lawyer'] = $this->input->post('o_lawyer');
    $save['fees'] = $this->input->post('fees');
    $save['city_case'] = json_encode($this->input->post('city_case'));
             
     $p_key = $this->cases_model->save($save);
    $reply = $this->input->post('reply');
     if(!empty($reply)){
     foreach($this->input->post('reply') as $key => $val) {
      $save_fields[] = array(
       'custom_field_id'=> $key,
       'reply'=> $val,
       'table_id'=> $p_key,
       'form'=> 2,
      ); 
     
     } 
     $this->custom_field_model->save_answer($save_fields);
    }
    
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang('case_created'));
    redirect('admin/cases');
   
    
   }
  }  
  
  
  $data['page_title'] = lang('add') . lang('case');
  $data['body'] = 'case/add';
  
  
  $this->load->view('template/main', $data); 

 }
```

```css
in view / add.php


<select name="city_case[]" class="chzn col-md-12" multiple="multiple" >
         <option value="">--<?php echo lang('select_city')?>--</option>
         <?php foreach($city as $new) {
           $sel = "";
           if(set_select('city_case', $new->id)) $sel = "selected='selected'";
           echo '<option value="'.$new->id.'" '.$sel.'>'.$new->name.'</option>';
          }
          
          ?>
         </select>
```

```html
models / cases_model.php


function get_name_city ()
 {
  $query = $this->db->get ('user_role');
  return $query->result();
 }
```

I replace code of add.php with another code , he work nice

-- --
                                    id)) $sel = "selected='selected'";
                                            echo 'id.'" '.$sel.'>'.$new->name.'';
                                        }

```
                                    ?>
                                </select>
```

Comment: do the tutorial in the codeigniter manual it will answer most of your questions including all about inserting into a database. next - when you are building something new - start simple and then build out. like in this case start with just a couple of form fields. get that working. then add the rest of the fields. its much faster to find errors that way.

Answer (score 0):

For inserting data into Table of database using codeigniter you have to maintain the sequence as
1.Get the values from view to controller , you have done properly as

```
            $save['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
            $save['case_no'] = $this->input->post('case_no');
            $save['client_id'] = $this->input->post('client_id');
            $save['location_id'] = $this->input->post('location_id');
            $save['court_id'] = $this->input->post('court_id');
            $save['court_category_id'] = $this->input->post('court_category_id');
            $save['case_stage_id'] = $this->input->post('case_stage_id');
            $save['case_category_id'] = json_encode($this->input->post('case_category_id'));
            $save['act_id'] = json_encode($this->input->post('act_id'));
            $save['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
            $save['start_date'] = $this->input->post('start_date');
            $save['hearing_date'] = $this->input->post('hearing_date');
            $save['o_lawyer'] = $this->input->post('o_lawyer');
            $save['fees'] = $this->input->post('fees');
            $save['city_case'] = json_encode($this->input->post('city_case'));
```

2.Pass the data to model but make sure that the fields name of Database table are same as your sending **$save[]** array indexes.

```
$p_key = $this->cases_model->save($save);
```

3.Write your data inserting proper Active record or RAW sql code which is not correct in your given sample. So follow below code active record code...

```
  public function save($save){
        $this->db->insert('YOUR_TARGETED_TABLE_NAME',$save);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Thank You!

Comment: Thank you Abu Muaz ,  but all data insert into database already , but field city_case doesn't insert , if I replace this field by another filed such as act_id , it insert correctly , Iam sure the problem in this field , can you help me ?

Comment: when i change type 
<option value="">--<?php echo lang('select_city')?>--</option>
<?php foreach($city as $new) {
  $sel = "";
if(set_select('city_case', $new->id)) $sel = "selected='selected'";
echo '<option value="'.$new->id.'" '.$sel.'>'.$new->name.'</option>';
 }?>

Comment: @ahmedgamal please try below  code snap                                                                                                                                             <?php foreach($city as $new) { ?>
  <option value="<?php  echo $new['id'];   ?>" <?php if(array_search($new['id'], $city_case) !== false) {echo 'selected';} ?>><?php  echo $new['name'];} ?></option> 
  <?php } ?>

Comment: [Reference1 ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493097/set-multiple-select-list-options-to-selected-from-query)                                          [Reference2 ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812056/how-to-show-selected-multiple-options-of-drop-down-in-php)